# Performance problems with dict as a decision tree

Tags: python, performance, dictionary

I have a performance problem here I guess with I am not sure what to call this, but it has a decision tree like appearance.

The program is supposed to cope with quite a bit of data in short intervals. Depending on the data the program should figure out which action to set. Most of the time it works. But sometimes not all of the data has not been processed (tested with the same data) I get OSC messages as strings from an external program with an interval of about a 1ms (maybe less). PythonOSC processes them a bit and sends it then to this function:

```
nextAction = {
   "nextAction1": doSomethingElseA,
   "nextAction2": dosomethingElseB,
   "nextAction3": nextActionA
}

action = {
   "action1": doSomethingA,
   "action2": dosomethingB,
   "action3": nextAction
}

def check(address, value):

   keywords = address.split('/')

   try:
       if len(keywords) == 2:
           action[keywords[1]](value)

       if len(keywords) == 4:
           action[keywords[1]][keywords[3]](int(keywords[2]), value)

   except KeyError:
       pass
```

There will be cases for more than 4 words as well (maybe 1-2 more). An address looks something like this `"x/address/2/here"` and a value is a `float`

Is there a better way to process this data to find out which action to set? Performance wise.

Comment: Your `action` dictionary shows no nested dictionaries. Dictionary lookups take constant time (O(1)) so you are unlikely to find further improvements there. How did you measure performance? How fast / slow are the **function calls** here?

Comment: The `cProfile` or `hotshot` modules will let you profile your code to figure out where the time is being used.

Comment: @MartijnPieters it does see in dict "action".. nextAction is embedded. I did with the current time. The results are always less than 1ms. Maybe I need a better performance measure technique.

Comment: @TomTomTom: ah, yes, missed that. Still, you have two O(1) lookups there, there isn't anything we can improve there.

Comment: @MartijnPieters At least I know there isn't much to improve. I have to look somewhere else for the culprit then! Thanks anyway.

Comment: How often do you hit the exception case?  If very often, probably faster to check for existence of the keys in the dicts first.

Comment: @JohnZwinck sometimes it is up to 100 times in a second. Is it worth it to check?

Comment: @TomTomTom: yes I would suggest adding the checks and removing the try/except.  It might improve things, but you'll have to time it yourself and see.